# SWT eclipse, remove a PainItem listener that was used to draw a table or tree table

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, listener, event-listener

I have used a PaintItem event listener (org.eclipse.swt.PaintItem) to draw a table tree. But that listener is always get called when i mouse over or select something on table. I want to remove that listener once its all painted or done with table rectangle draw. Please help. Below is the code snipped I am using:

```java
Listener l = new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.gc.setForeground(EclipseSupport.COLOUR_DKGRAY);
        event.gc.setLineWidth(2);
        int currentCol = event.index;
        Rectangle rect = ((TreeItem) event.item).getBounds(currentCol);
        event.gc.drawRectangle(rect);
    }
};

tree.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, l);
```

Comment: You need to keep the listener - SWT doesn't remember what you have drawn so you need to paint it whenever SWT wants you to. If you remove it you will find that what you have drawn may disappear .

Comment: Thanks Greg-449, you are right, If i remove the Listener, its getting disappear. But whats the solution for my problem:   Listener is always get called when i mouse over or select something on table. That i don't want.

Comment: That is just how SWT works - it will ask you to paint quite often, you just have to do that.

Comment: Note if you are use SWT.PaintItem you should also be using SWT.EraseItem and SWT.MeasureItem as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html). Or use the JFace TreeViewer with OwnerDrawLabelProvider.

Comment: Thanks , Actually i just wanted to make those rectangle white lines (in dark theme) to grey color. For that i was unable to change the color with tree.setLinesVisible(true);.  So i draw them manually using a listener and their color to grey. Is there any other way i can make white lines to grey without using a listener? if we only use a default table draw using tree.setLinesVisible(true); I am beginner in SWT. Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202935/discussion-between-bhupinder-singh-and-greg-449).